# Update not happening

Tags: update-manager

I found an error on right top of the screen in "red cricle" .
It say:

```
A problem occured while checking for updates.
```

I am not able to open open software updater and software center.

The result of "sudo apt-get update " is pasted below:

```
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease  
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease 
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg    
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release        
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trustyRelease                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                               
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates     InRelease                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main     Sources                               
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports     InRelease                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386  Packages                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security  InRelease                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed InRelease               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty  Release.gpg                               
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933   B]             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg                     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main    Translation-en_IN                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_IN
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main   Translation-en                        
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release         
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [63.5 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [63.5  kB]              
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed Release [211 kB]               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                   
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [194 kB]           
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [2,564 B]    
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [113 kB]      
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [4,775 B]   
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [491 kB]    
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [9,256 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [274 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [11.9 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en         
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [78.4 kB]        
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [2,061 B]  
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [20.9 kB]    
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [1,922 B]  
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [248 kB]   
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [8,846 B]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [99.4 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3,643 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en          
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe i386 Packages [31.3 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main i386 Packages [152 kB]   
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages [2,716 B]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted i386 Packages [3,271 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/universe Translation-en          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_IN                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN                
Fetched 2,092 kB in 56s (36.9 kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Done

sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

The output of running software-centre in terminal is:

```
ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 4, in <module> from debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 21, in <module> from apt.debfile import DebPackage
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 34, in <module> apt_pkg.init_config()
SystemError: E:Opening configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)
INFO:softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app:setting up proxy 'http://netmon.iitb.ac.in:80/'
2015-04-23 23:20:22,489 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'http://netmon.iitb.ac.in:80/'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module> app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 291, in __init__self.cache = get_pkg_info()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo.py", line 245, in get_pkg_info from softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache import AptCache
  File "/usr/share/software center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 39, in <module> class GtkMainIterationProgress(apt.progress.base.OpProgress):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'progress'
```

Comment: Open a terminal and run this command: `sudo apt-get update` and post the output in your question.

Comment: I am adding the last fews line of the comment .                                                    

Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_IN              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_IN              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_IN                
Fetched 2,351 kB in 1min 27s (27.0 kB/s)                                       
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: Not the last line, post all messages. Use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/611910/edit) funktion and improve your question.

Comment: I cannot post entire message since I don't have 10 reputation for posting more than 2 url.

Comment: Sure? You have more than 10.

Comment: I have added the terminal output of : sudo apt-get update. Please comment

Comment: So far, no error occurs. Ok, than run `sudo apt-get upgrade`. And post the error if there is one.

Comment: The output from sudo apt-get upgrade is updated in question.

Comment: Hmmm, no errors. Run `software-center` in a terminal and update the question.

Comment: Added the ouput of software-centre in terminal to the question. Also the edits are not getting properly indented. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Still the issue is unresolved

Comment: Please reply to it

Comment: Tried to upgrade system from usb. Although the upgrade didnot happen the problem is solved.